# Disable MySQL general logging without restarting?

Tags: mysql, logging

Can I disable general logging completely without restarting the server?

Because, per the documentation:

```
SET sql_log_bin = {0|1}
```

Disables or enables binary logging for the current connection (`sql_log_bin` is a session variable) if the client has the `SUPER` privilege. The statement is refused with an error if the client does not have that privilege.

Can I enable/disable general log without restarting MySQL?

Comment: @shantanuo: R u alive? Does the solution work?

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using 5.1 now, you can use these commands (had to look them up and this Q&A came up)

```
SET GLOBAL log_output='TABLE'; #or FILE

SET GLOBAL general_log='OFF'; #or ON

SET GLOBAL slow_query_log='ON'; #or OFF
```

TABLE will store them in the mysql.general_log and mysql.slow_log tables instead of files which is nice in development for reviewing and truncating.

Comment: Thanks for informations. Are the confs saved after a server reboot ?

Comment: @zeflex no, you have to add it to the my.cnf file to keep the settings.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.0 "The session `sql_log_off` variable can be set to `ON` or `OFF` to disable or enable general query logging for the current connection." [[MySQL Doc, Log file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html)]